# Localization of Telerik Reports with different Cultures- in MVC application

Tags: telerik, multilingual, telerik-reporting

I am currently working on Telerik Reporting with localization.i am new to telerik reports.please Can any one help me how to localize telerik reports to display in the language of a specific culture in my MVC application. For example, my report has to be displayed in both English and Malay as per user request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. We walk through  this"[Localization in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.chambaud.com/2013/02/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-4/) "article,and we rechecked what mistake we done previously,we follow all the steps which mentioned in ther [telerik reporting official document](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports.html) but we missed settings in route.config file. now the issue is resolved by applying those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Add localization in Telerik Report is made in a few steps (that you can easily find in the [official documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports.html)) :

1. Build your report as usual. Make it in English for instance.
2. Click anywhere on the report area then click right to open the report Properties window. There, set the report *Localizable* property to true.
3. Select Malay in the *Language* property list.
4. You can change the static text into Malay.

As you save the design view, you see that another resource file is created resulting architecture like this:

- MyReport.cs

  - MyReport.Designer.resx
  - MyReport.ms.resx
  - MyReport.resx
  - MyReport

Comment: Thanks for answer @Francois Stock, actually I done those things what you said already,but in my report doesn't create any another resource files related to my selected language , i manually created my required language resource files and added to the report and and i done some little bit code in my global.asax. file. now it works fine for me.                           Sorry about my (poor) English.